# Computer freezes when breakpoint is used on a certain tool's event

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

When I use a breakpoint on my `combobox.SelectedIndexChanged` event, my whole computer stops working. It freezes and then goes back to normal when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>. What could it be? This happens only with the `ComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged` event.

Additionally, sometimes I have to restart the MySql service to see the results of my insert and update queries. What could be causing this?

Comment: Are you using the latest version of mysql?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Your MySQL problem sounds completely unrelated to the breakpoint issue, so you should post it as a separate question.

Comment: Thanks for the welcome hehe, it's version is 5.0.19. But if has nothing to do with the `breakpoint` why it just happens with the event of the `ComboBox` ?! ;\. It's filled with items from a table throught a `DataSet`... What you think ?

Comment: Do you run any queries when SelectedIndexChanged event is ran?